# Pop up dialog no matter what the user is doing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I hope this isn't a duplicate of a similar question but haven't been able to find anything that helped me.

I'm creating a simple egg timer, and it works very well. Though I am struggling one thing.
When the timer runs out, an alarm starts and an activity shown as a dialog pops up. Though this happens only if the app i open. If I open another app and the alarm goes off nothing happens.

So my question is, how do I make the dialog pop up no matter what the user is doing?

At the moment my method for displaying the dialog looks like this:

```
private void ShowTimesUp(){
    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TimesUpDialog.class);
    dialogIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(dialogIntent, 1);
}
```

and the manifest looks like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".Home"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".TimesUpDialog" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog"></activity>
```

Comment: how are you setting your timer? Are you using a broadcast receiver? If so edit your post and include the code for it. [Also see here](http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/) for a tutorial on alarms that may help. You can replace the Toast in this example and change it to startActivity(), that will make it pop up your Activity when the alarm fires no matter what is currently running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static final int TIMEOUT = 60 * 1000;
```

...

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TimesUpDialog.class);
    dialogIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(YourApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext(), 0,
            dialogIntent, dialogIntent.getFlags());

AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + TIMEOUT, intent);
```

I think you will not need any other timer logic.

P.S.: I did not test this, hope it helps.

**Edit: a possible solution for the question mentioned in below comment**

> *Now I am just wondering if it is possible to get a result from the
>   intent started by the AlarmManager?*

The above code should be changed to this:

```
Intent startApplicationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    dialogIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startApplicationIntent.putExtra(START_DIALOG, true);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(YourApplication.getInstance().getBaseContext(), 0,
            startApplicationIntent, startApplicationIntent.getFlags());

AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + TIMEOUT, intent);
```

Now in your `MainActivity`'s `onStart()` method you could do the following:

```
boolean startDialog = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(START_DIALOG, false);
if (startDialog) {
    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimesUpDialog.class);
    startActivityForResult(dialogIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CONSTANT);
}
```

Where `START_DIALOG` is a String constant defining an intent extra value's key and  `MainActivity` is the Launcher activity.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This just works @GyuriMajercsik! Now I am just wondering if it is possible to get a result from the intent started by the AlarmManager?

Comment: Glad it worked for you, don't forget to accept the answer... Now, related to the second question... I think it is possible. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: I can't get the code posted in the edit to work, however just to clarify for myself, the TIMEOUT constant just postpone when the intent should show right?

The reason i want the result from the dialog is to simply turn off the alarm when the user pushes a button in the dialog. Could i turn off the alarm inside the dialog, but adding the alarm object to the dialog intent and then use your initial suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you turn off the alarm exactly when the user presses the right button ?

Comment: This is also what i might just end up doing.
My initial idea was to have the timer fire off the dialog when it finished and show the user a button to press. But I might just skip the dialog.